# The TableView problem...How to know the row number

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

`what I am doing`

I am making a project in which I am using a tableView. In that tableView I have a delete Button in every row..

`what I want`

I want that When I press the button ...there is a delay of 1 second. and after that the row should be deleted..in that time of delay the delete button of the row that I pressed should be hide.

`My Problem`

Well I am able to do this thing but there is a problem. When I press the delete button of any row ...only the delete button of the last row hides...

`Root of the problem -According to my view`
Well I have assigned the delete button in cellForRowAtIndexPath ..
and I have assigned the method for it...when I press the button...The method get called..in that method I have made that delete button hidden...

I mean how would it know that In which row that delete button should be hide...

`My Question`
When I press the delete button how to know in which row that should hide..Now its hiding every time in the Last row only..

Suggestion Pls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
[myButton addTarget:self
                             action:@selector(ButtonAction:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

myButton.tag = indexPath.row ;
```

implement the below method,

```
-(void) ButtonAction:(id) sender
{
    UIButton* myButton = (UIButton*)sender;
    myButton.hidden = YES;

    //Delete the row at index (myButton.tag)

}
```

I would suggest you to use custom cell rather then using UITableViewCell directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try setting tag for each of the delete buttons as the row number and then access the tag in the button click method to know which button was clicked.

Comment: @7kv7...okay...suppose I have the number of the delete button which is pressed...then how can I hide that perticular button?? suppose button no 5 is pressed.and I have the tag no 5..then what to do?? coz I am executing the delete.hidden=YES command when I press the send button...:(..how would I know that the delete button of row no 5 should be hidden??

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that doesn't rely on tags:

```
-(void)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[button superview] superview];
    [button setHidden:YES];
    [self.tableView performSelector:@selector(deleteCell:) withObject:cell afterDelay:0.5]

-(void)deleteCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell
{
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:cell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation{YourChoiceHere}
}
```

Comment: @Rog...Can you answer my this question..I am stuck again..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389124/the-tableview-problema-view-with-indicator-in-perticuler-row

Answer (score 0):

Try this: First set a unique tag to every cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
    [cell setTag:10000+[[userInfo objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]];
```

After wards, for deletetion use function like this:

```
-(void)deleteRow:(id)sender{
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];
[YOURTABLEVIEW deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:0];
```

}

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: @Prabh...thanks for help bro...can you answer this question?? I am stuck again...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389124/the-tableview-problema-view-with-indicator-in-perticuler-row

Answer (score 0):

to know the row number, you can get it by indexpath.row