# The TableView problem…A view with indicator..in particular row

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uilabel, uiactivityindicatorview

Few hours ago I did ask this Question ..And my problem got solved..

[The TableView problem...How to know the row number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387925/the-tableview-problem-how-to-know-the-row-number)

Now in this question I want to add this..

`what I am doing`

I am making a project in which I am using a tableView. In that tableView After deleting the row A new view should be shown on that row with activity indicator and a label...and label shows...row deleted..

`My Problem`

Again I am stuck with the problem that is when I press the button ..the button of the particular row that I have pressed...the button is getting hidden in that row but the view and the activity indicator is again can be seen in the last row...EVERY TIME

I tried the same thing that I did successfully tried in the procedure of hiding button...which is the answer of the last question I have given the link above..However it is giving me an error..

what to do now?

Comment: Can you post your code of cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to get the cell:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```